# How to manually connect to heroku database using DB URI

Tags: git, heroku

Whenever I try connecting to the Heroku Database using **heroku pg:psql**. It says it's connecting and in the Heroku dashboard it says it's connected, but it never shows the connection in the git terminal, so I can't enter any commands.

I've been able to connect before by using the database URI, but I can't remember how I did it and all my combinations of heroku pg:psql + URI isn't working.

What do I need to do to connect (other than what the Heroku documentation already says), or is there another way to fix the hang after I connect?

Edit: Figured it out. Removing heroku and just using psql + URI allowed me to connect.

Comment: What does "never finishes the connection in git" mean? Git and Postgres are entirely different things? Do you mean you're running `heroku pg:psql` from "Git Bash" on Windows? This is just a shell, it doesn't really have anything to do with Git. It's part of the environment Git ships with on Windows.

Comment: Right, I was just saying Git as in, the place where I am monitoring the connection. Using the command "heroku pg:psql" just leaves me with "--> Connecting to postgresql-name-number" but it never shows that it connects in the git terminal